# C Bubble sort read access viloation issue

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, bubble-sort, function-definition

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNING
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void bubbleSort(int matrix[9], int n);

int main(void) {


    int matrix[9];
    int n = 9;
    printf("enter 10 values to the matirx \n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("now %dth componet\n ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &matrix[i]);
    }

    bubbleSort(matrix[9], n);
    return 0;

}



void bubbleSort(int matrix [9], int n) {

    //bubble sort the given matrix
    int temp = 0;

    for (int i=n-1; i > 0; i--) {

        // compare two values at j and j+1 and move left when j+1 is smaller than j 
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {

            if (matrix[j] > matrix[j + 1]) {
                temp = matrix[j];
                matrix[j] = matrix[j + 1];
                matrix[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
        
        printf("Check the matrix \n");

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            printf("%d ", matrix[i]);
            }
        
        printf("\n");

    }

}
```

Hi, I am getting a read access violation error at

```
            if (matrix[j] > matrix[j + 1]) {
                **temp = matrix[j];**
                matrix[j] = matrix[j + 1];
                matrix[j + 1] = temp;
            }
```

This part of the code. The code builds right, but when I run the program I get an error. Can anyone help me out to figure out the issue? I searched up a little bit and based on that I assume it has something to do with the pointer but I do not know why there would be an issue with a pointer since I never used it in my code.

Comment: How are you going to enter 10 numbers for the array int matrix[9]; that contains only 9 elements?

Comment: `assert (j+1 < n)`

Comment: `bubbleSort(matrix[9], n)`: This is using element #9 of your array as the parameter, not the address of the 9-element array.  You want `bubbleSort (matrix, n)`.  And @VladfromMoscow is right on array size: `int matrix [9]` creates a 9-element array with elements 0 through 8.  You want `int matrix [10]` as your declaration.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow paxdiablo, (760k rep), is obviously in need of more coffee this morning:)

Comment: @paxdiablo,  The statement: `matrix[9]` has valid indexes of 0.1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8  An index of 9 would be beyond the end of the array.

Comment: Absolutely right, bods, it's embarrassing that someone who's been using C for forty-ish years could make such a basic brain-fart. My apologies, I'll put it down to lack of sleep caused by a broken wrist from several weeks ago and I'll be a bit more circumspect before pressing ENTER for a bit :-)

Answer (score 4):

For starters you declared an array that contains only `9` elements.

```
int matrix[9];
```

On the other hand, you are trying to enter `10` elements.

```
printf("enter 10 values to the matirx \n");

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("now %dth componet\n ", i+1);
    scanf("%d", &matrix[i]);
}
```

So the program already has undefined behavior.

In this function declaration

```
void bubbleSort(int matrix[9], int n);
```

the magic number `9` used in the declaration of the first parameter does not make a great sense. Just write

```
void bubbleSort(int matrix[], int n);
```

or

```
void bubbleSort(int *matrix, int n);
```

In this call

```
bubbleSort(matrix[9], n);
```

instead of passing the array `matrix` like

```
bubbleSort(matrix, n);
```

you are passing the non-existent element of the array `matrix[9]`. The compiler should issue a message that you are trying to convert an integer to a pointer.

Within the function you are using the magic number `9` instead of the parameter `n` in this loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
```

Pay attention to that it looks strange when a one-dimensional array is named matrix.

Using your approach the program can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bubbleSort( int matrix[], size_t n ) 
{
    if ( n )
    {
        for ( size_t i = n - 1; i != 0;  i-- ) 
        {
            // compare two values at j and j+1 and move left when j+1 is smaller than j 
            for ( size_t j = 0; j < i; j++ ) 
            {
                if ( matrix[j + 1] < matrix[j] ) 
                {
                    int temp = matrix[j];
                    matrix[j] = matrix[j + 1];
                    matrix[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 9 };
    int matrix[N];

    printf( "enter %d values to the matirx \n", N );

    for ( int i = 0;  i < N; i++ ) 
    {
        printf( "now %dth componet\n", i+1 );
        scanf( "%d", matrix + i );
    }

    bubbleSort( matrix, N );
    
    for ( int i = 0;  i < N; i++ ) 
    {
        printf( "%d", matrix[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look

```
enter 9 values to the matirx 
now 1th componet
9
now 2th componet
8
now 3th componet
7
now 4th componet
6
now 5th componet
5
now 6th componet
4
now 7th componet
3
now 8th componet
2
now 9th componet
1
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: @TrueRoughly Select the best answer to close the question.

Answer (score 2):

```c
bubbleSort(matrix[9], n);
```

This passes just the final *element* of the list (coerced into an address) rather than the *actual* address of the list, which is what you probably intended.

That won't end well :-)

You should just pass in `matrix`.

---

A decent compiler should warn you of this, such as with `gcc`:

```
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:21:22: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘bubbleSort’
              makes pointer from integer without a cast
              [-Wint-conversion]
   21 |     bubbleSort(matrix[9], n);
      |                ~~~~~~^~~
      |                      |
      |                      int
prog.c:7:21: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of
             type ‘int’
    7 | void bubbleSort(int matrix[9], int n);
      |                 ~~~~^~~~~~~~~
```